# Change QT5 theme

Tags: 15.10, qt5, i3-wm

I am using i3wm on Ubuntu 15.10.
I was wondering on how to change the QT5 theme?
With old QT4 it was possible to change it with qt4-config. There is however no qt5-config as of yet.
I have tried using qt-config-tool, but it segfaults on launch.
There is also lxqt-config, but it is only in xenial repositories, and I need it for willy.
So is there an elegant way to change QT5 themes with Ubuntu 15.10?
Also, what is the package name of the KDE system settings, so that I try to apt-get it? Will it pull all of KDE to my system or just some qt libs?

Comment: QT5 has only one theme: Fusion. You can launch QT5 apps with "-style=fusion" argument to see it.

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution.  Can't I install other themes?

Answer (score 8):

The package/app you're looking for is [qt5ct](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qt5ct/) which is the new and much better version of the old qt(4)config for qt5.

With it you can customise almost every aspect of your qt5 apps. You can set fonts, icon theme, colour schemes and widget styles, other small interface feauters and Qt style sheets ([qss](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html)) to be applied globally to all qt5 apps. And you can save your colour schemes with different names and easily change between them.

As to the widget styles you can install qtcurve, [kvantum](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum) and [virtuality](https://github.com/luebking/virtuality) (in addition to the preinstalled GTK+, Windows and Fusion).

[image]

Comment: While your answer may be valid it lacks on content, please provide proper steps and aswll have a look at [Editing Help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to see how you can format your post nicely